# Webhook response with "suggestion chips"

Tags: webhooks, actions-on-google, api-ai

I would like to guide users based on webhook response with suggestions chips. From webhook sample, I see below structure:

```
"fulfillment": {
  "speech": "Today in Boston: Fair, the temperature is 37 F",
  "source": "apiai-weather-webhook-sample",
  "displayText": "Today in Boston: Fair, the temperature is 37 F"
}
```

But, if I want to suggest users what next you can request to continue the conversation, then how do I pass suggestions chips in webhook response?

Comment: What webhook sample, exactly, are you looking at?

Comment: @Prisoner - From these links: https://docs.api.ai/docs/webhook & https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#json ,I am not sure how to merge both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The response you displayed is the basic API.AI response format. However, Actions on Google expands on this and mainly uses the data.google field as presented below:

```
{
  "speech":"This is a simple response with suggestion chips",
  "data": {
    "google":
    {
      "expectUserResponse":true,
      "richResponse":
      {
        "items":
        [
          {
            "simpleResponse":
            {
              "textToSpeech":"This is a simple response for with suggestion chips"
            }
          }
        ],
        "suggestions":
        [
          {
            "title":"Option 1"
          },
          {
            "title":"Option 2"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It is important to note, that this only displays suggestions for an actions-on-google application, it won't do anything for stuff like Facebook etc.