# dynamically add suggestion chips on Api.ai for Actions on google

Tags: artificial-intelligence, bots, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I want to add suggestions for the user in my Google Assistant Bot. I am using API.ai for bot development and using fulfilment, I am communicating with my backend for data. 
I am not able to send suggestions using suggestions chips to my bot.

 I have followed as answered here [Webhook response with "suggestion chips"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44380416/webhook-response-with-suggestion-chips)
as well as the document at https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#json.
But still, I only see simple text response at my bot on device as well as on simulator.
I also checked at https://discuss.api.ai/t/google-assistant-rich-message-responses/5134/19. But didn't find any way to switch to V1 or V2. The sample format also didn't work!

Here are my 2 JSONs:
**at API.ai**

```
"fulfillment": {
  "speech": "want to proceed further?",
  "messages": [
    {
      "type": 0,
      "speech": "want to proceed further?"
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "google": {
      "conversationToken": "[\"AS-PER-JSON-FROM-SIMULATOR\"]",
      "expectedInputs": [
        {
          "inputPrompt": {
            "richInitialPrompt": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "simpleResponse": {
                    "textToSpeech": "want to proceed further?",
                    "displayText": "want to proceed further?"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "suggestions": [
                {
                  "title": "Yes"
                },
                {
                  "title": "No"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
},
```

**at action on Google**

```
"expectUserResponse": true,
    "expectedInputs": [
        {
            "inputPrompt": {
                "richInitialPrompt": {
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "simpleResponse": {
                                "textToSpeech": "want to proceed?"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "noMatchPrompts": [],
                "noInputPrompts": []
            },
            "possibleIntents": [
                {
                    "intent": "assistant.intent.action.TEXT"
                }
            ],
            "speechBiasingHints": [
                "$subject",
                "$answer"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

**python server**

```
return = '{"speech":"want to proceed?", "data": {"google":{"expectedInputs":[{"inputPrompt":{"richInitialPrompt":{"items":[{"simpleResponse":{"textToSpeech":"want to proceed?","displayText":"want to proceed?"}}],"suggestions":[{"title":"Yes"},{"title":"No"}]}}}]}}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is wrong, remove the quotation mark before the data object:

```
"data" : { ... }
```

instead of

```
"data" : "{ ... }"
```

So basically, you're sending a string containing the object instead of a JSON object.

Comment: I think I had tried that option. Let me check and confirm.

Comment: I have updated my code and sending "data":{....} still not working :( Please see update to my question above.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using format as explained here https://developers.google.com/actions/apiai/webhook

Answer (score 0):

Add `'expectUserResponse'` into `data` -> `google`

```
'expectUserResponse': true,
'isSsml': false,
```